# Change highlight color of buttons in Roku screen templates

Tags: roku, brightscript

In Roku BrightScript, is there any way to change the default black highlight color for the active button in various screen types?

There are several options in [roAppManager](http://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/roAppManager) to change the text color of buttons, such as `ButtonNormalColor`, `ButtonHighlightColor`, `ButtonMenuNormalText`, `ButtonMenuNormalOverlayText` and `ButtonMenuHighlightText`, but I can't find any way to change the color of the focus from the default black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Received the following answer at the [Roku developer forum](http://forums.roku.com/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=87670#p494580):

*"I don't think we implemented any hooks for those. The newer Theme attributes added to the documentation were found by someone combing through the source code looking for undocumented theme attributes, so its already been combed."*